# Can't insert hardware breakpoint with GDB

Tags: gdb, breakpoints, gdb-python

I tried to set watch into address

`(gdb) watch 0x7536546` but I got an error
Warning:
Could not insert hardware watchpoint 6.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requests too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints

That the first hardware breakpoint that I have tried to insert

What is the problem and what can I do ?

Comment: Please edit your question to say which OS and what version of GDB you are using, as well as explaining where the `0x7536546`  address camer from.

Answer (score 2):

`(gdb) watch 0x7536546`

Above command instructs GDB to wait until expression `0x7536546` changes, but it never will -- that expression will forever remain `0x7536546`.

You *probably* wanted to watch the *value* stored at address `0x7536546`. To do so, the command to use is:

```
(gdb) watch *(int*)0x7536546
(gdb) watch *(long*)0x7536546
```

Adjust the type to whatever type is stored at the given address.